# High scale message processing in eventhub

Tags: azure, autoscaling, azure-eventhub

As per my understanding, eventhub can process/ingest millions of messages per seconds. And to tune the ingesting, we can use throughput.

More throughput= more ingesting power.

But on receiving/consuming side, You can create upto 32 receivers(since we can create 32 partitions and one partition can be consumed by one receiver).

Based on above, if one single message takes 100 milisencond to process, one consumer can process 10 message per second and 32 consumer can process 32*10= 320 message per second.

How can I make my receiver consume more messages (for ex. 5-10k per seond).

1) Either I have to process message asynchronously inside ProcessEventsAsync. But in this case I would not be able to maintain ordering.

2) Or I have to ask Microsoft to allow me to create more partitions.

Please advice

Comment: Hi @Pragmatic, with 32 partitions and 10 TU i could receive 6 lacks message in 10 min. observed that, with 20 TU it reduced to 5 min. but increasing TU may end up paying more money. If you have resolved this already please share your comments. as I would like to get all 6 lacks messages to process in 1 min or lesser.

Answer (score 6):

TLDR: You will need to ask Microsoft to increase the number of partitions you are allowed, and remember that there is currently no way to increase the number on an already extant Event Hub.

You are correct that your unit of consumption parallelism is the partition. If your consumers can only do 10/seconds in order or even 100/second in order, then you will need more partitions to consume millions of events. While 100ms/event certainly seems slow to me and I think you should look for optimizations there (ie farm out work you don't need to wait for, commit less often etc), you will reach the point of needing more partitions at scale.

Some things to keep in mind: 32 partitions gives you only 32 Mb/s of ingress and 64Mb/s of egress. Both of these factors matter since that egress throughput is shared by all the consumer groups you use. So if you have 4 consumer groups reading the data (16Mb/s each) you'll need twice as many partitions (or at least throughput units) for input as you would based solely on your data ingress (because otherwise you would fall behind).

With regards to your comment about multitenancy, you will have one 'database consumer' group that handles all your tenants all of whose data will be flowing through the same hub? If so that sounds like a sensible use, what would not be so sensible is having one consumer group per tenant each consuming the entire stream.

Comment: if you already have and event hub and need to improve on the consuming speed - one more solution to consider is piping event hubs (feeding the data from busy partition of the EventHub to another eventHub) and then consume from the new 32 partitions (which are split from single partition).

Comment: While @Sreeram 's comment is probably your only real approach for an existing event hub, the downside of doing that is you end up paying twice for each event ($0.028/Million). The upside is you also get another set of 5 (4 for safety) consumers per partition which is a limitation I hadn't noted in my answer.